# download and store google street view panoramas based on lat/long

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, codeigniter, google-maps

I have a data set of locations (9000 records) which I have long/lat for.  I would like to give each location a photo.  It would be neat to use google street view photos for this.  I dont want to rely on the service, rather I would prefer to store the images on my end.

Is there a way to have my server pull in the images from the google maps api if I provide long/lat?  If someone could point me in the right direction that would certainly help.

I can implement this via php or ruby/rails.

My other concern is the legality of doing so, but I would assume this may not be the right place to ask that question.

Comment: An excerpt from _Google Maps/Earth Additional Terms of Service_ (http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html) follows: "(d) use the Products in a manner that _gives you or any other person access to mass downloads or bulk feeds_ of any Content, including but not limited to numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, _imagery_, and visible map data", and "(g) use the Products to create a _database of places or other local listings information_". My guess is your application would violate the ToS (

Answer (score 2):

[The Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) might be of interest. You can just grab the image from them [like this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&sensor=false), then store it like you would any other file. No idea what licensing implications this might have.

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&sensor=false

Comment: thats a good start. the tricky part will be getting the pov.  think i can get this using the JS api, but that wouldnt help me server side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068365/getting-the-pov-for-google-streetview-api <- shows how to get pov using js api

Comment: You could definitely get a street view through the JS API, but you specifically said you wanted to store it locally, which the JS API does not do.